# fstab mount network share to older smb dd-wrt versions

Tags: samba, share

I have been having a problem mounting a samba share of my dd-wrt to my rpi3.

- My targer was dd-wrt linksys wrt1900ac v1.0 samba share
- My problem: unable to mount it in anyway (also fstab from rpi3 or straight from cli). Source: RPi3 - Target ddwrt router samba share (public)
  Errors from not begin able to pass the password to reference to *mount.cifs* to *invalid argument error 22*.
  I came across this post:
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64420/cannot-mount-samba-share-mount-error-22

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! We work different to other internet forums in that we use a question and answer model. Could you please edit your question to include just the problem. You can then post an answer on this question explaining your solution; you should also mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add **vers=1.0** to the options on mount. It seems it is a kernel issue that mounts SMB (*thats is my understanding from reading a lot about this issue*)
PS
That works with credentials or for a samba share that is public (without credentials)
I hope that helps you

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. This has been a long-standing issue with Raspberry Pi. I would have thought it would be fixed by now, but the `vers=1.0` addition is still required.